# jqPlot legends for donut chart not displaying color-swatches/box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot, legend, donut-chart

I have a very simple problem

**Code :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var s1 = [['Status',600], ['Pictures',800], ['Starred',140], ['Comments',200]];
  //var s2 = [['a', 8], ['b', 12], ['c', 6], ['d', 9]];

  var plot3 = $.jqplot('chart3', [s1], {
    seriesDefaults: {
      // make this a donut chart.
      renderer:$.jqplot.DonutRenderer,
      rendererOptions:{
        // Donut's can be cut into slices like pies.
        sliceMargin: 3,
        // Pies and donuts can start at any arbitrary angle.
        startAngle: -90,
        showDataLabels: true,
        // By default, data labels show the percentage of the donut/pie.
        // You can show the data 'value' or data 'label' instead.
        dataLabels: 'label'
      }
    },

    grid: {
    drawGridLines: true,        // wether to draw lines across the grid or not.
      // *Color of the grid lines.
    background: 'white',      // CSS color spec for background color of grid.
    borderColor: 'white',     // CSS color spec for border around grid.
        shadow: false       
    }  ,legend: { show:true, location: 'e' }      

  });
});
```

Now the legend does show up but not in a way it should it shows up like this ..[image]

No colours , no box. what am I doing wrong. I did as the documents said.. anyone?

Comment: For me its working check http://jsfiddle.net/devmgs/1xcn4bf5/ can you check in console if any error occurs for your setup

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you forget to include the jqPlot CSS file.

Make sure you have included `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/raw/b5a7796a9ebf/src/jquery.jqplot.css" type="text/css"/>`

And then things should work out for you.

Well, if you have already included the jqPLot CSS file, then we will have to check it, and spot the problem.

Hope it helps.